# Enable admin theme in my install profile

Tags: users, installation

Is it possible to enable an admin theme in my install profile?

Used this:

```
// Enable themes
  $enable = array(
    'theme_default' => 'geoslate',
    'admin_theme' => 'adminimal_theme',
  );
  theme_enable($enable);

  foreach ($enable as $var => $theme) {
    if (!is_numeric($var)) {
      variable_set($var, $theme);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to set the relevant variable (`admin_theme`), e.g.

```
variable_set('admin_theme', 'seven');
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 you can add this to your `my_custom_profile.install` file:

```
<?php

  function my_custom_profile_install() {
    // Set 'Seven' as the default administration theme
    \Drupal::configFactory()
      ->getEditable('system.theme')
      ->set('admin', 'seven')
      ->save();
```